# Can we have both Static and dynamic partition in same query ? if yes then how the folder will be created.?

Tags: hive, hadoop2

Can we add static and dynamic partition in same query . If yes the how the folder will be created as per below data?

1. We have data of different  country and its state .
2. We do static partition on country="US" and do dynamic partition on state.

How the folder structure will be created in HDFS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The folder structure would be created hierarchically depending on the order you use in your table definition. For instance, if you defined your table using something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
   column1 INT, 
   column2 STRING
   ...
   columnN FLOAT
)
PARTITIONED BY (country STRING, state STRING);
```

You could define a static value for the country and a dynamic value for state. In this case, you are specifying the value for the static partition in advance ('US') and you are letting Hive to read through the values of the column "state" (on each row of the `SELECT` query) and to dynamically create the folder (a unique HDFS path) for each state.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE your_partitioned_table
PARTITION (country = 'US', state)
SELECT T.column1, T.column2, ..., T.country, T.state
FROM your_table T
WHERE T.country = 'US';
```

Your HDFS folder structure would be something like this:

```
.../your_table/country=US/state=CA
...
.../your_table/country=US/state=NY
```

[Here](https://www.altiscale.com/blog/best-practices-for-dynamic-partitioning-in-hive/) you have a excellent guide on how to use dynamic and static partitions in Hive.

Comment: Continuation to above question and answer .for Non US country data how the folder structure will be created? Assume that in static partition we only specify country=US;

Comment: In that case, since you're setting the value 'US', no folder will be created for non-US countries, because you're selecting data just from US in the WHERE clause. If you wanted data from all countries, you would have to use dynamic partitions also for the country (i.e. don't set a country value)

Comment: Hi , Since we have mentioned country as static partition, do we need country column value in the select/ file ? Could you please advise

Comment: no, the static column can be skipped from the list of columns mentioned in SELECT since it's already mentioned in the partition clause of the query -- I have tested it, it works by omitting that