# Creation of a hive table having static as well as dynamic partitions together

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to create a hive table having static as well as dynamic partition at the same time. How can we create such table? What properties we need to set?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183175/can-we-have-both-static-and-dynamic-partition-in-same-query-if-yes-then-how-th

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have both Static and dynamic partition in same query ? if yes then how the folder will be created.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183175/can-we-have-both-static-and-dynamic-partition-in-same-query-if-yes-then-how-th)